# Pyspark summarising the results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i have created a spark DF which include around 20 columns. All these are updated with 0, 1 . I need to aggregate the result.

For example:-
I have col1 col2 ….
All these are updated with 0,1 .

I want to pull out a summary as :-

```
Values| Col1 | col2 
  0     Count  count
  1     Count  count
```

That will give us, how many zeros are there in col1 and how many 1s.

Comment: Please share your code and tell us what difficulty you've had so far creating the output you expect

Comment: Just tried doing that on one column. Like sparkdf.groupby(“col1”).agg({“col” : ‘count}). However, need to run the steps on all columns and need summary in 2rows with 20columns with counts.

Comment: You could write a for loop over each of the column names

Comment: Please can you advise on this. I tried . For col in sparkdf.schema.names:

Comment: Does this example help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56257865/2308683

Comment: Yes. It does. Will give it a try on my dataset. Seems straight forward. Thanks